# How to add multiple values using chip

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

In my project, I have an email field to implement using the chip component.
But I am facing a problem here, first time, when I paste multiple email values it gets inserted into the field, but second time when I copy some other values and paste them into the field, it replaces the previous values.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import './styles.css';


export const TagActions = () => {
    const [items, setItem] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [error, setError]= useState('')
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false)

    const handleDelete = (item:any) => {
        console.log("handleDelete", item)
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
      };
    
    const handleItemEdit = (item:any) =>{
        console.log("handleItemEdit", item)
        const result = items.filter(i => i !== item)
        setItem(result)
        setValue(item)
        console.log("value", value)
        
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (evt:any) => {
        if (["Enter", "Tab", ","].includes(evt.key)) {
          evt.preventDefault();

          var test = value.trim();
    
          if (test && isValid(test)) {
            items.push(test)
            setValue("")
           
          }
        }
    };

    const isValid = (email:any)=> {
        let error = null;
    
        if (isInList(email)) {
          error = `${email} has already been added.`;
        }
    
        if (!isEmail(email)) {
          setFlag(true)
          // error = `${email} is not a valid email address.`;
        }
        
        if (error) {
            setError(error);
    
          return false;
        }
    
        return true;
    }

    const isInList = (email:any)=> {
        return items.includes(email);
      }
    
    const isEmail = (email:any)=> {
        return /[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/.test(email);
    }

    const handleChange = (evt:any) => {
        setValue(evt.target.value)
        // setError("")
        
    };

    const handlePaste = (evt:any) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    
        var paste = evt.clipboardData.getData("text");
        var emails = paste.match(/[\w\d\.-]+@[\w\d\.-]+\.[\w\d\.-]+/g);
    
        if (emails) {
          var toBeAdded = emails.filter((email:any) => !isInList(email));
            
            setItem(toBeAdded)
        
        }
    };
    


    return (
        <>
          <div>
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined"
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: items.map(item => (
              <Chip
                className={!isEmail(item) ? "chip-tag-error": "chip-tag"}
                key={item}
                tabIndex={-1}
                label={item}
                onDelete={() => handleDelete(item)}
                onClick={() => handleItemEdit(item)}
              />
            )),
  
          }}
            ref={divRef}
            value={value}
            placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`..."
            onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onPaste={(e) => handlePaste(e)}
          />
          </div>
  
          {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </>
      );
}
```

Please give me a solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `Autocomplete` with `renderTags` function here is an example

```js
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  Autocomplete,
  Chip,
} from '@mui/material'
...
const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm()
...

<Box mt={2}>
    <Controller
    control={control}
    name="tags"
    rules={{
        required: "Veuillez choisir une réponse",
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
        defaultValue={
            useCasesData?.tags ? JSON.parse(useCasesData?.tags) : []
        }
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        options={[]}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
            value.map((option, index) => (
            <Chip
                variant="outlined"
                label={option}
                {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
            ))
        }
        onChange={(event, values) => {
            onChange(values);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Métadonnées"
            placeholder="Ecriver les métadonnées"
            helperText={errors.tags?.message}
            error={!!errors.tags}
            />
        )}
        />
    )}
    />
</Box>
```

[image]